# Phrase Search in SQL Server 2008 (T-SQL)

Tags: t-sql, search, phrase

I have a `varchar` column with 3 rows:

```
i eat orange,
orange,
oranges are nice
```

I want `SELECT` query to return the result in this order:

```
orange, oranges are nice, i eat orange
```

i.e. those matches that **start** with the `'keyword'=orange` should come before those that **contain** the keyword which again should come before those that **ends** with the keyword.

How can I do this using T-SQL? I tried using the `LIKE` keyword but no success so far.

Comment: read up on full-text indexes. You can do this with like (see below), but it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 WHERE column LIKE '%' + keyword + '%'
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN column = keyword THEN 0
               WHEN column LIKE keyword + '%' THEN 1
               WHEN column LIKE '%' + keyword + '%' THEN 2 END
```

But really, for this kind of search you want to use a full-text index.

Comment: I like your solution, it is a bit more precise, but I think you need to add one more condition (i.e. column LIKE '%'+keyword THEN 3) to get the strings ending with the keyword pushed to the back..

Comment: @Sparky - mine only sorts into three (or four) blocks, though. Yours will rank in order of first appearance.

Comment: True, but mine will not work if the last occurrence of the keyword occurs in a string substantially shorter than another matching string.  Maybe if we combine your case statement, with my order, we can get something that works (or we can convince him to use full text indexing)

Comment: @Sparky - You guys are correct. Combining your logic does the job for me. I will also research "full text indexing" way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following order by clause (assuming your WHERE clause returns only matches)

```
ORDER BY charIndex(keyword,col_name),length(col_name)
```

This will put the earliest occurrence of the keyword first.